# Interactive messages only appear below the last message

Tags: java, slack, bolt

Click 'Approve' and 'Yes' respectively

[image]

Question: As shown in the figure above, I received two messages in slack. Whether I click the 'Approve' button or the 'Yes' button, the returned message only appears below the last message. Why? I hope the returned message will only appear under the button I clicked. How to do?

Please help, thank you!

My code is as follows:

```
app.blockAction("button-action", (req, ctx) -> {
  Response respond= ctx.ack();
  String value = req.getPayload().getActions().get(0).getValue(); // "button's value"
  if (req.getPayload().getResponseUrl() != null) {
    // Post a message to the same channel if it's a block in a message
    ctx.respond("You " + value + " it");
  }
  return respond;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with the slack messages, you can either post a new message or edit the existing one.

The implementation you are using can only post message at the end of the conversation.

If you really want to attach your response to the **original message**, then you should try threading the reply.